# Currency Format change in the Device, Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am using XCODE 4.
In My app I am using NSCurrencyFormatter Code...

```
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle]; 
  ... = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

Problem is On Device Instead of $ it shows RS.
In  simulator it works fine with $.

Comment: What region settings do you have on the device?

Comment: Check Settings/General/International (probably the 'Region Format' is for currency - among others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just need to change the iphone setings..
Settings --> General --> International -->Region Settings to Whichever country I need to make.
Then My currency will set on Iphone according to this..